# How to make Raspberry Pi connect to my Wifi using headless method?

Tags: pi-3, headless, raspberry-pi-os

I have followed many tutorials (actually they have been doing the same thing) on how to set Raspberry Pi to connect to my WIFI but I am not winning. I have used the Headless method and my network file which is named **wpa_supplicant.conf** is on the Boot directory with the following information but yet using Angry IP Scanner the Raspberry Pi is not showing please help:-

```
country=ZA
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="wifiyes"
    psk="password"
}
```

My

I wrote my RPi OS using the official Raspberry Pi Imager as seen in the below image and that was successful as it also shows boot files when opened on my Windows laptop.
[image: Image Writer]

Comment: You have not provided any diagnostics but how did you create the file. You need to use a Unix compatible editor which uses LF rather than CRLF

Comment: @Milliways I created the in my windows system using Notepad and save it. I unfortunately don't know anything about LF and CRLF let me also google about them.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to download Notepad++ [DownloadLink](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) , open your wpa_supplicant.conf file with it, go to Edit>EOL conversion and select Unix LF

Hope this helps.